# I have to create a table with 96 columns . is it efficient or not ? but 96 columns must be in the table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 96 columns . the problem is i get confused for create this table with a large amount of columns.

Comment: So don't create a table with 96 columns. Or do, and get confused. I don't see what we can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

## Don't do that, then!

It's rare to genuinely need a table with that many columns. Most likely, you will be able to split the data across multiple tables into a [relational database](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19615/Introduction-to-Relational-Databases--Part-1-Theoretical-Foundation.htm). For example, if, in your long table, each record contains the name of a product, the price of the product, the store that sells the product, and the address of the store, you will usually want to have separate `Stores` and `Products` tables, probably with a [many-to-many relationship](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) between them.

To a large extent you can do so without much thought, by putting your database into some [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), typically the [third normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). These normal forms are chosen to have nice properties when you want to insert, update, or delete a record. However, you usually have to think about the meaning of the data you store to find a decomposition that makes sense. A lack of repetitions in the initial data doesn't mean there won't be any later.

## Read more

Those concepts are well explained in the [Manga Guide to Databases](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593271909.do).

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21696/more-than-20-columns-in-database-table-mysql/21699#21699) gives an example of a situation that requires partitioning, and [another answer by the same user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6607/how-does-table-partitioning-help/6610#6610) explains the performance benefits. (Besides not confusing oneself.)

## But I need to!

In some odd situations, you might genuinely need a long table. Maybe you're starting a club for people who have exactly 95 names and so you need to store an identifier key (since there is no natural primary key in this case) and each of the names in order. In that case, you will have some test data you can use to immediately verify that the table has the correct format.

To avoid getting confused, it might help to use pen and paper (or a blackboard): write out the test data in the order that's most natural, find a reasonable name and format for each column, and then work off that when writing your table creation procedure. The line numbers in your editor should be enough to make sure you haven't skipped a column.